# Does weak continuity imply continuity?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I have come across the following excerpt from a mathematical Statistics book:

[image]

where $H$ and $J$ are Hilbert spaces and $H^{\star}$ is the dual space. For me, the statement after Definition 10 is unconvincing and I cannot, in general, show that weak continuity implies continuity. In particular, if $x_n$ converges strongly to $x$, then it also converges weakly and by weak continuity $f(x_n)$ converges weakly to $f(x)$. However, we need $f(x_n)$ to converge strongly to $f(x)$ in order to have continuity and it's not clear to me how we can obtain this.

I expect this to be true when $J$ is finite-dimensional as in that case weak and strong convergence are equivalent but other than that I am at a loss. I was wondering then, is the book wrong on this?

Comment: That is something of a mess. Definition 10 defines *weak sequential continuity*, not *weak continuity*. For Hilbert spaces (and some more general spaces) these notions coincide, but not in general. Weak continuity implies strong continuity and continuity with respect to the Mackey topologies for Hausdorff locally convex spaces, but not generally the continuity with respect to the originial topologies. Weak sequential continuity in general doesn't imply strong or Mackey continuity. As the answer shows, for Hilbert spaces the claims hold (except for the "Clearly"), but that takes machinery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Clearly' should not have been there but the result is true. This  require the so-called Closed Graph Theorem (CGT). If $x_n \to x$ and $f(x_n) \to  y$ in the norm then  $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ weakly and it converges to $y$ in the norm (hence also weakly) and this implies $y=f(x)$. By CGT it follows that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Why does $f(x_n) \to y$ in the norm? We can only assume that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ weakly.

Comment: I closed graph theorem you **assume** that $x_n \to x$  in the norm and $f(x_n) \to y$ in the norm and show that $y=f(x)$. That is  enough to prove that $f$ is continuous. (You don't start with $x_n \to x$ and try to  show directly that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ in the norm. This  theorem  is very powerful). @JohnK

Comment: Yes but this doesn't follow from weak continuity. This is the only thing we assume here.

Comment: @JohnK For CGT see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. The question is about how weak continuity implies strong continuity. To apply the CGT you need additional assumptions.

Comment: You are attempting ti prove the result from definitions. That is not easy. I am using a powerful theorem to prove that weak continuity implies strong contunuity. CGT uses only completeness of $H$ and $J$ and linearity if the map $f$. I am not making any additional assumptions.

Comment: What I do not understand is why $f(x_n) \to y$ in the norm. If we assume only weak continuity (as I do in the question) we only have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ weakly. Many thanks for your comments.

Comment: I now understand your point. Thanks a lot.